# Problem with refreshing values in redux reducer. Why can't I create action and assign new values of state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I can't update my store values using action creator. All needed values I get from component normally, but just can't substitute the initial state values with them. I believe I made a stupid mistake or even misspelled something, but I spent a lot of time already, and the console in the browser still shows me the empty strings in that reducer's state.

```
let initialstate = {
    login: "",
    password: ""
}

const formReducer = (state = initialstate ,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET-FORM-DATA': {
            return {
                ...state,
                login: action.login,
                password: action.password
            }    
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}

export const SetFormData = (login, password) => ({
    type: 'SET-FORM-DATA', login, password
})

export default formReducer;
```

That formReducer is normally assigned in redux-store

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './auth-reducer';
import dialogsReducer from './dialogs-reducer';
import profileReducer from './profile-reducer';
import usersReducer from './users-reducer';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
**import formReducer from './form-reducer';**

let reducers = combineReducers({
    profilePage: profileReducer,
    dialogPage: dialogsReducer,
    usersPage: usersReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    form: formReducer
})

let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

window.store = store;

export default store;
```

I call this action creator on submit of form like that:

```
 const onSubmit = formData => {
        props.SetFormData(formData.Login, formData.password)
 }
```

And this call seems to be, luckily works alright

Comment: Your reducer and action creator are fine.  I'm concerned with why you are doing `window.store = store` instead of accessing the store through a `react-redux` `Provider` component.  @Ueslei's answer assumes that you are just calling `SetFormData` without attaching it to `dispatch`, but if your component is getting `props.SetFormData` from the `react-redux` `connect` HOC then there is no issue there.  Are you?  Does your form `render` function call the `handleSubmit` argument?  I need to see more of your component in order to know what's wrong.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Well, I think I could avoid that trouble just by not dispatching data from my form into the store. I learned that react final form is not really compatible with redux reducers as in my example. That happens because it does not support submitting my form via a side-effect. But I luckily found a library that can be useful in that case.
You can find out more here: 
https://medium.com/@erikras/getting-a-promise-from-redux-actions-d92787894368

Answer (score 0):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

I didn't quite understand the problem, but to handle redux we must use `dispatch`. You are not using this, you are just passing redux values. Sorry if I got it wrong, but I use something like this:

```
import { createTypes } from "reduxsauce";

export const gradesTypes = createTypes(
  `
  SET_GRADES
  RESET_STATE
`,
  { prefix: "GRADES/" }
);

const setGrades = (grades) => {
  return (dispatch) => dispatch({ type: gradesTypes.SET_GRADES, grades });
};
const resetState = () => {
  return (dispatch) => dispatch({ type: gradesTypes.RESET_STATE });
};

export const gradesActions = {
  setGrades,
  resetState,
};
```

Comment: That's a interesting solution. But it wouldn't work either. I researched that the question is more about corresponding between react final forms and react-redux. And it's quite challenging :) I am trying to write a custom middleware to dispatch async function. Trying through redux-thunk, it technically might work. But your advice helped me with understanding a lot. Thank you!